# How do I set a customized message when sharing on Facebook using Addthis?

Tags: facebook, addthis

I'm trying to set a custom message when sharing a page (via facebook) using the addthis module. So far, I've been successfully able to set a custom title, description and image ([here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing#.UVkeSqspa0w) is the reference I used), but I also need to be able to set a custom message on the textbox where the sharer would be able to put in a comment.

Is there anyway to do that using the addthis module?

Comment: Well it's not technically a file.

Comment: @CamiloMartin What do you mean that it's not technically a file? I'm only referring to setting the comment when sharing. How does a file relate to this?

Comment: The title says "using the Addthis file", but you're talking about the URL to the script that parses such things I believe.

Comment: Platform Policies explicitly forbid pre-filling the message part – it has to be typed by the user themselves.

Comment: To specify the message for a user, you would have to use the Facebook Graph API and post the message for the user.  You wouldn't use AddThis to do this, check out https://developers.facebook.com/web/ and look at the SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

According to [Platform Policy 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) it is not allowed to

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo album captions.